# How do I calculate permutation?

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I am having a question about permutation in Java.

Suppose I have five different elements in an array [a, b, c, d, e] and I want to select three elements out of them, the order does matter. I know in math we can use <sub>5</sub>P<sub>3</sub> to get the answer, but can we use Java to get the count and the complete list of elements of the permutation set of <sub>5</sub>P<sub>3</sub>?

Comment: not entirely sure I understand what you're asking for, it looks like you just want P53 in java?

This link has it all: 

https://github.com/atapazvant/Project-Euler/blob/master/Project-Euler/src/project/euler/solutions/p53.java

Comment: Do you want to return all the permutations, or do you just want to return the number of permutations?

Comment: I want all the permutations and the number of all permutations. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "1, 2, 3" is different from "2, 1, 3", I will suggest the following code snippet. Note that i can't be identical to j or k to avoid "1, 1, 1" or "1, 3, 3" scenarios.

```
   // array with elements
   char[] items = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
   int count = 0;

    // first of the "three"
    for (int i = 0; i < upperBound; i++) {
       // second of the "three"
       for (int j = 0; j < upperBound; j++) {
          // can't be identical to i
          if (j == i) 
             continue;

          // third of the "three"
          for (int k = 0; k < upperBound; k++) {
             // can't be identical to i or j
             if (k == i || k ==j) 
                continue;

             // print some display
             System.out.println(items[i] + ", " + items[j] + ", " + items[k]);

             // increment the total count
             count++;
          }
       }
    }



    System.out.println("Total count is " + count);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Thx @Joe. Revised per advice.

Comment: Thx @RyanL. 

Suppose I have i items in an array like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ….i-2, i-1, i]
I wanna select j elements out of them, the order does matter, how can we use Java to get the value of jPi and all results?

Comment: Hi Minghua, did you mean iPj instead?

Comment: sorry for my typo. 
select j items from i, the order does matter. it's similar to the code you just provided (like select 3 items from a five items array [a, b,c,d,e]), but the number of the for loop is a variable. Thx@RyanL

Comment: @Minghua, thx for acknowledging this answer. However, I am still working on your n element solution. Hopefully I can get something and let you know.

Comment: @RyanL check out this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949030/print-all-possible-permutations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-integer-array-of-size-n

Comment: Thanks @MinghuaZheng for pointed out. There seems to have some similarities in there :)

Comment: @MinghuaZheng, here's what I am thinking about your IPJ scenario. (note that J is different from j. J is a pre-determined number of items to take out from the collection of I. Here we go: for(j = 0; j < J; j++) {pickedItemList.add(j); GetItem(pickedItemList); } void GetItem(ArrayList pickedItemList) { for(i = 0; i < I; i++) {// if i is not in a arraylist, arraylist add (i), otherwise continue; GetItem(pickedItemList); }} As you see above from the "incomplete pseudo code snippet", recursion is applied. I said it's incomplete because defensive coding to guard against infinite looping is needed.

Comment: @RyanL, thx. You are right. I will do more resarch about recursion.