# print all possible permutations of r elements in a given integer array of size n in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, permutation

Given an array of size n, generate and print all possible permutations of r elements in array.

For example, if n is 4, input array is [0, 1, 2, 3], and r is 3, then output should be

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 3, 1]
[0, 3, 2]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 0]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 3]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 0]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 0, 1]
[3, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 0]
[3, 2, 1]
```

All elements in the input array are integers, from 0 to n-1. How can I use Java to print all possible permutations?

**Important: the number of all elements in a single permutation is not always the size of original array. It's less or equal to the size of original array. Additionally, the order of elements in each permutation does matter.**

I have written some code when n=4 and r=3. If n = 100 and r = 50, my code will be really ugly. Is there any smart way to do this when parameters are only n and r?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // original array
    ArrayList < Integer > items = new ArrayList < > ();

    // all permutations
    ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer >> allPermutations = new ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer >> ();

    // define the end item of the original array.
    // this is n, suppose it's 4 now.
    int endItem = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < endItem; i++) {
        items.add(i);
    }


    // r means how many elements in each single permutation
    // suppose it's 3 now, i have to write for-loop three times
    // if r is 100, i have to write for-loop 100 times

    // first of the "r"
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        // second of the "r"
        for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++) {
            // can't be identical to i
            if (j == i)
                continue;

            // third of the "r"
            for (int k = 0; k < items.size(); k++) {
                // can't be identical to i or j
                if (k == i || k == j)
                    continue;

                // a single permutation
                ArrayList < Integer > singlePermutation = new ArrayList < > ();
                singlePermutation.add(items.get(i));
                singlePermutation.add(items.get(j));
                singlePermutation.add(items.get(k));

                // all permutations
                allPermutations.add(singlePermutation);

            }
        }
    }
    for (ArrayList < Integer > permutation: allPermutations) {
        System.out.println(permutation);
    }
    System.out.println(allPermutations.size());

}
```

Comment: GIYF: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html

Comment: Princeton has some examples. 2 links: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/CombinationsK.java.html and http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/PermutationsK.java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **Solution:**
>
> Thanks to [older coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7332484/older-coder), I managed to find the solution.
>
> ```
> public class PermutationTest10 {
>     // a is the original array
>     // k is the number of elements in each permutation
>     public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> choose(ArrayList<Integer> a, int k) {
>         ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPermutations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
>         enumerate(a, a.size(), k, allPermutations);
>         return allPermutations;
>     }
>
>   // a is the original array
>     // n is the array size
>     // k is the number of elements in each permutation
>     // allPermutations is all different permutations
>     private static void enumerate(ArrayList<Integer> a, int n, int k, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPermutations) {
>         if (k == 0) {
>             ArrayList<Integer> singlePermutation = new ArrayList<Integer>();
>             for (int i = n; i < a.size(); i++){
>                 singlePermutation.add(a.get(i));
>             }
>             allPermutations.add(singlePermutation);
>             return;
>         }
>
>       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>             swap(a, i, n-1);
>             enumerate(a, n-1, k-1, allPermutations);
>             swap(a, i, n-1);
>         }
>     }  
>
>   // helper function that swaps a.get(i) and a.get(j)
>     public static void swap(ArrayList<Integer> a, int i, int j) {
>         Integer temp = a.get(i);
>         a.set(i, a.get(j));
>         a.set(j, temp);
>     }
>
>
>   // sample client
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>       // n is the end item of the array.
>         // if n = 5, the array is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>         // k is the number of elements of each permutation.
>         int n =5;
>         int k =3;
>
>       // create original array
>         ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<> ();
>         for (int i =0; i < n; i ++){
>             elements.add(i);
>         }
>
>       ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<> ();
>         for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
>             a.add(elements.get(i));
>         }
>         System.out.println(choose(a, k));
>     }
> }
> ```