# How to display all possible permutations of an array

Tags: java, combinations, permutation, combinatorics, permute

I'm working on Permutations in Java. My program to is supposed to generate all possible permutations of an array with length *n* and arrange in *r* number of permutations.

Here is an example. For an array with these 12 elements

```
string  Mywords[] =("love" ,"guy" ,"cow","hen","dog","antelope","cat" "rat",welcome","thank","you","all");
```

Where

```
n=12, r=7
```

7 of the 12 elements are selected to create 12 possible variations of the array.

**=>> output may be in form (possible case)**

1. (love, guy, cow, hen, dog, antelope, cat)
2. (love, cow, guy, hen, dog, antelope, cat)
3. (love, hen, guy, cow, dog, antelope, cat)
4. (love, dog, hen, guy, cow, antelope, cat)
5. (love, thank, dog, hen, guy, cow, welcome)
6. :
7. :
8. :
9. :
10. :
11. :
12. P(n,r)

How can I print all possible results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print out all permutations of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387185/print-out-all-permutations-of-an-array)

Comment: That doesn't help please!

Comment: What about this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array

Comment: If it doesn't help, please explain more clearly what problem it is that you are having.  See  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: It helps if you post the code you created to output the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is adapted from the answer to this SO question.

[print all possible permutations of r elements in a given integer array of size n in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949030/print-all-possible-permutations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-integer-array-of-size-n)

That question uses a list of integers. In the below code I essentially only replaced `Integer` with `String`.

Note that the number of permutations of 7 elements from a list of 12 elements is close to 3.5 million which will take time. Hence in the below code I generate permutations of three elements from a five element list.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {

    public static List<List<String>> choose(List<String> a, int k) {
        List<List<String>> allPermutations = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        enumerate(a, a.size(), k, allPermutations);
        return allPermutations;
    }

    // a is the original array
    // n is the array size
    // k is the number of elements in each permutation
    // allPermutations is all different permutations
    private static void enumerate(List<String> a,
                                  int n,
                                  int k,
                                  List<List<String>> allPermutations) {
        if (k == 0) {
            List<String> singlePermutation = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = n; i < a.size(); i++) {
                singlePermutation.add(a.get(i));
            }
            allPermutations.add(singlePermutation);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            swap(a, i, n - 1);
            enumerate(a, n - 1, k - 1, allPermutations);
            swap(a, i, n - 1);
        }
    }

    // helper function that swaps a.get(i) and a.get(j)
    public static void swap(List<String> a, int i, int j) {
        String temp = a.get(i);
        a.set(i, a.get(j));
        a.set(j, temp);
    }

    // sample client
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create original array
        List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>(List.of("love",
                                                        "guy",
                                                        "cow",
                                                        "hen",
                                                        "dog"));
        int n = elements.size();

        // k is the number of elements of each permutation.
        int k = 3;

        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a.add(elements.get(i));
        }
        choose(a, k).forEach(list -> System.out.println(list));
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output.

```
[hen, dog, love]
[guy, dog, love]
[cow, dog, love]
[dog, guy, love]
[hen, guy, love]
[cow, guy, love]
[dog, cow, love]
[guy, cow, love]
[hen, cow, love]
[dog, hen, love]
[guy, hen, love]
[cow, hen, love]
[hen, love, guy]
[dog, love, guy]
[cow, love, guy]
[love, dog, guy]
[hen, dog, guy]
[cow, dog, guy]
[love, cow, guy]
[dog, cow, guy]
[hen, cow, guy]
[love, hen, guy]
[dog, hen, guy]
[cow, hen, guy]
[hen, love, cow]
[guy, love, cow]
[dog, love, cow]
[love, guy, cow]
[hen, guy, cow]
[dog, guy, cow]
[love, dog, cow]
[guy, dog, cow]
[hen, dog, cow]
[love, hen, cow]
[guy, hen, cow]
[dog, hen, cow]
[dog, love, hen]
[guy, love, hen]
[cow, love, hen]
[love, guy, hen]
[dog, guy, hen]
[cow, guy, hen]
[love, cow, hen]
[guy, cow, hen]
[dog, cow, hen]
[love, dog, hen]
[guy, dog, hen]
[cow, dog, hen]
[hen, love, dog]
[guy, love, dog]
[cow, love, dog]
[love, guy, dog]
[hen, guy, dog]
[cow, guy, dog]
[love, cow, dog]
[guy, cow, dog]
[hen, cow, dog]
[love, hen, dog]
[guy, hen, dog]
[cow, hen, dog]
```